# How can i make parallel threads with using moveToThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

So, I'm trying to make two threads which work parallel, capturing frames from OpenCV in an infinite loop and returning that frames in (2 labels) main window.

I'm tried to create new instances of my class and move it to a different thread.

```cpp
void ThreadT::updateWin(Mat i)
{
    /*ui.label->setText(QString::number(i));*/

ui.label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(i.data, i.cols, i.rows, i.step, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()));
}

void ThreadT::updateWin2(Mat i)
{
    /*ui.label->setText(QString::number(i));*/

    ui.label2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(i.data, i.cols, i.rows, i.step, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()));
}






void ThreadT::on_pushButton_clicked() {
QThread* thread = new QThread;

QSignalMapper* signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
    Cap* CP = new Cap();
    CP->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(CP, SIGNAL(Stream(Mat)), this, SLOT(updateWin(Mat)));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    signalMapper->setMapping(thread, 1);
    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), CP, SLOT(run(int)));
    thread->start();



QThread* thread2 = new QThread;
QSignalMapper* signalMapper2 = new QSignalMapper(this);
    Cap* CP2 = new Cap();
    CP2->moveToThread(thread2);
    connect(CP2, SIGNAL(Stream(Mat)), this, SLOT(updateWin2(Mat)));
    connect(thread2, SIGNAL(started()), signalMapper2, SLOT(map()));
    signalMapper2->setMapping(thread2, 0);
    connect(signalMapper2, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), CP2, SLOT(run(int)));
    thread2->start();

}
```

I expected to see 2 labels with different frames from my webcams, but unfortunately, it's forking only for one thread, if 1st thread is working, then second give's me an error:

> Invalid number of thread provided.

Comment: What does moveToThread() do? Does it only store one thread in Cap?

Comment: QThreadPool /thread